# Wrapping Rails Model structure with a JSON Key before generating payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that is in the following format:

```
rails generate model Location name:text latitude:text longitude:text
```

I would serve it in the following way:

```
render json: { location: @location } #retrieved column
```

However when retrieving the data from the DB and serving them as a json payload, I would like to wrap the latitude and the longitude in a different key and serve it in the following format:

```
{
   "name": "New York",
   "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "12.23543", 
      "longitude": "2.44556"
   }    
}
```

How can I edit my model structure to serve this format?

Comment: Did you consider writing a custom `as_json` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which you can structure your JSON response.

1. One is to override as_json method inside the model class.
2. You can use Active Model Serializers for more complicated JSON structure.
3. Alternatively you can also use [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).

You can override the `as_json` method in the location model class using the following code snippet.

```
class Location

  def as_json(options={})
   method_arr = [:coordinates]
   super(except: ['created_at', 'updated_at'],methods: method_arr)
  end

  def coordinates
    {'latitude_key_name'=> latitude, 'longitude_key_name'=> longitude}
  end 
end
```

Comment: But how will this affect when a new record is created? For example if I want to insert a new row using: `@location = Location.new(....parameters I pass in...`. I just tried this snippet and I got this error: `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'coordinates' for Location.):`

Comment: This won't affect the new record creation. Please note `coordinates` is a method, not an attribute.  You should create the record in the same way you were doing earlier.
`Location.new(name: '', longitude: '', latitude: '')`

Comment: Thank you for your time. The row is inserted in the DB but when rendering the json, I get this error now: `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'this'. app/models/location.rb:9:in 'coordinates'.
app/models/location.rb:5:in 'as_json'`